# Question about C struct - same type, no compatibility?

Tags: c

While studying C and programming language principles, i got a problem with struct declarations.

```
struct{
    int i;
    double j;
} x, y;
struct{
    int i;
    double j;
} z;
```

Assigning x = y does not cause an error while
x = z causes error. Can't understand why this is happening. They have same structure, so I thought these would be compatible.

Also, the problem says that there would have two different ways to fix the code.
The first thing would be letting z next to x, y;
I don't get another way to find it.
Any suggestions would be welcome. Thank you

Comment: The other/more ways are in the code you do not show. Consider making a [mre].

Comment: Another way is to name the first structure. Then declare `struct name z;`

Answer (score 2):

> **6.7.2.3 Tags**
> ...
> 5    Two declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in different scopes or
> use different tags declare distinct types. **Each declaration of a structure, union, or
> enumerated type *which does not include a tag* declares a distinct type.**

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added. `z` is considered to have a distinct type from `x` and `y`, even though it has the same representation.

The proper way to fix this is to declare the `struct` with a tag name:

```
struct foo {
  int i;
  double j;
} x, y;
```

and then declare `z` using that same tag:

```
struct foo z;
```

Comment: With citation from the standard, link and example, this is a great answer.